# Get error in Swing java - IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, swing, layout

Tried to put on frame some swing components. 
This code worked to days ago. Now it's not work, didn't nothing.
Maybe somebody can tell me what it's wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame();
    mainFrame.setSize(500, 400); //Size of frame
    mainFrame.setTitle("Cinema City"); //Set title
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 

    JLabel mainLabel = new JLabel("Welcome to Cinema City catalog!");
    JLabel actorLabel = new JLabel("Actors: ");
    JLabel laLabel = new JLabel("Last added: ");
    JLabel searchLabel = new JLabel("How to search ?");

    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

    mainFrame.add(mainLabel, new GridBagConstraints(4, 0, 1, 3, 1, 1,
            GridBagConstraints.NORTH, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
            new Insets(20, 160, 0, 0), 0, 0));

    mainFrame.add(actorLabel, new GridBagConstraints(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1,
            GridBagConstraints.NORTHWEST, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL,
            new Insets(100, 0, 0, 0), 0, 0));

    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
```

This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: cannot add to layout: constraint must be a string (or null)
at java.awt.BorderLayout.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JRootPane$1.addLayoutComponent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at GUI.main(GUI.java:40)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Layout is not mentioned for the particular JFrame - `mainframe`

Add this line after the JFrame declaration

```
mainFrame.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
```

Should work fine.

Answer (score 3):

You're not actually setting your layout to `GridBagLayout`, so it is still the default (which would be a `FlowLayout`).

Of course, only a `GridBagLayout` can actually handle `GridBagConstraints`.
This can be fixed by changing your declaration to `JFrame mainFrame = new JFrame(new GridBagLayout());`

Answer (score 0):

you are not set frame layout .
after creation object of frame write this code.

```
 new GridBagLayout();
 mainFrame.setLayout(gbl);
```

its work